# Gson: Is there more efficient ways to do custom (de)serialization of a verbose Json object

Tags: json, gson

I am working with some json objects that I call verbose:

```
{
  "user": {
    "name": "username",
    "email": "blah@blah.com",
    "time_zone": "America/New_York"
  }
}
```

But I'd prefer to just deal with them in terms of java POJOs like:

```
class UserDetails {
    String name;
    String email;
    String timeZone;
    ...
}
```

Note that I have no control over the POJO as it is generated code.

My two requirements for (de)serialization is that

- the `timeZone` field maps to `time_zone` in JSON
- the outer `user` is ignored

So I have some customer (de)serializers:

```
    class UserDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<UserDetails> {
        @Override
        public UserDetails deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
            throws JsonParseException {
            JsonElement content = je.getAsJsonObject().get("user");
            UserDetails userDetails = new GsonBuilder()
                .setFieldNamingStrategy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                .create()
                .fromJson(content, UserDetails.class);
            return userDetails;
        }
    }

    class UserSerializer implements JsonSerializer<UserDetails> {
        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(UserDetails userDetails, Type typeOfSrc,
                                     JsonSerializationContext context) {
            JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
            JsonElement je = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setFieldNamingStrategy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                    .create().toJsonTree(userDetails);
            obj.add("user", je);
            return obj;

        }
    }
```

I feel like creating new Gson objects in the (de)serializer logic is not ideal/efficient just to add and remove the outermost `user` key.

EDIT: Actually `.setFieldNamingStrategy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)` does work fine on deserialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really think it's a good idea in general, and you should probably better have a single `Wrapper<T>` for all "top-most" purposes (if you don't want your inner objects to be considered "verbose").
But you're right when you say

> I feel like creating new Gson objects in the (de)serializer logic is not ideal/efficient just to add and remove the outermost user key.

So:

- Creating a `Gson` is a relatively expensive operation.
- This just creates unnecessary objects and hits the heap.
- `Gson` may be configured in a special way and you might want to share the same `Gson` configuration everywhere.
- `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer` operate on JSON trees (`JsonElement` and its subclasses), therefore it creates an intermediate in-memory tree representations before/after serialization/deserialization.

You might consider a faster solution, that's free of those items.

```java
final class VerboseTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private final Map<Class<?>, String> mappings;

    private VerboseTypeAdapterFactory(final Map<Class<?>, String> mappings) {
        this.mappings = mappings;
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory get(final Map<Class<?>, String> mappings) {
        // Create a defensive copy to make sure the map is not modified from outside
        final Map<Class<?>, String> mappingsCopy = mappings
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
        return new VerboseTypeAdapterFactory(mappingsCopy);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        final Class<? super T> rawType = typeToken.getRawType();
        // Not something we can handle?
        if ( !mappings.containsKey(rawType) ) {
            // Then let Gson do its job elsewhere
            return null;
        }
        // Getting a property name we want to use for a particular class
        final String propertyName = mappings.get(rawType);
        // And getting the original type adapter for this class (effectively ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.Adapter)
        final TypeAdapter<T> delegateTypeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken);
        return VerboseTypeAdapter.get(propertyName, delegateTypeAdapter);
    }

    private static final class VerboseTypeAdapter<T>
            extends TypeAdapter<T> {

        private final String propertyName;
        private final TypeAdapter<T> delegateTypeAdapter;

        private VerboseTypeAdapter(final String propertyName, final TypeAdapter<T> delegateTypeAdapter) {
            this.propertyName = propertyName;
            this.delegateTypeAdapter = delegateTypeAdapter;
        }

        private static <T> TypeAdapter<T> get(final String propertyName, final TypeAdapter<T> delegateTypeAdapter) {
            return new VerboseTypeAdapter<>(propertyName, delegateTypeAdapter)
                    // A convenient method to simplify null-handling
                    .nullSafe();
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T object)
                throws IOException {
            // Open the object with `{`
            out.beginObject();
            // Prepend the object with its reserved name
            out.name(propertyName);
            // Write the object
            delegateTypeAdapter.write(out, object);
            // And close the object with `}`
            out.endObject();
        }

        @Override
        public T read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            // Assume the very first token is `{`
            in.beginObject();
            // Peeking what's the actual property name
            final String actualPropertyName = in.nextName();
            // And if it's not we expect, throw a JSON parse exception
            if ( !actualPropertyName.equals(propertyName) ) {
                throw new JsonParseException("Expected " + propertyName + " but was " + actualPropertyName);
            }
            // Otherwise read the value led by the property name
            final T object = delegateTypeAdapter.read(in);
            // And make sure there are no more properties
            if ( in.hasNext() ) {
                throw new JsonParseException(propertyName + " is expected to be the only top-most property");
            }
            // Assume the very last token is `}` (this works for the check above, but we made it more semantical)
            in.endObject();
            return object;
        }

    }

}
```

So, for example, the following code

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setFieldNamingStrategy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(VerboseTypeAdapterFactory.get(ImmutableMap.of(UserDetails.class, "user")))
        .create();

...

final UserDetails userDetails = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, UserDetails.class);
System.out.println(userDetails.name);
System.out.println(userDetails.email);
System.out.println(userDetails.timeZone);
final String json = gson.toJson(userDetails);
System.out.println(json);
```

produces

```
username
blah@blah.com
America/New_York
{"user":{"name":"username","email":"blah@blah.com","time_zone":"America/New_York"}}
```

As the conclusion:

- No more excessive `Gson` instantiation.
- Original `Gson` instance configuration inherited (i.e. `FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` set once).
- No intermediate `JsonElement` instances.

Comment: What are good/valid use cases for Json(De|S)erializer then? Or are they just relics and now writing a custom TypeAdapter(Factory) is the best practice?

Comment: @jshort I would use them if I: 1) need to create either a serializer or a deserializer; 2) don't care for performance; 3) don't care for intermediate tree objects. `JsonSerializer`/`JsonDeserializer` might also be much easier to use when the object structure tends to be complex, and it's much easier to use `JsonElement` interface (you traverse it in arbitrary depth or query keys/elements in arbitrary order) rather than to write a complex logic in a type adapter that uses streaming mode (you read token by token and build a state machine yourself)